# Nodejs Cluster with socket.io loses connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, cluster-computing

I am using node.js with cluster module in order to create multiprocess socket.io server.

Using [this](https://github.com/elad/node-cluster-socket.io) example I have created the following server-client application:

**Server:**

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

// Start master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Create slave workers (in this example there is only one)
    var worker = cluster.fork();

    // Starts a server that will delegate the connection to the worker
    var routerServer = net.createServer(function(connection) {
        worker.send({type: 'new_connection'}, connection);
    });

    routerServer.listen(443, "my-ip-address");
} else {
    // Start a server on random Port
    var slaveHttp = require("http").Server();
    slaveHttp.listen(0, "localhost");

    // Connect socket.io to the server
    var io = require('socket.io')(slaveHttp);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected");
    });

    // On server messsage (new connection) emit it to the server
    process.on('message', function(message, handle) {
        if (message.type == 'new_connection') {
            slaveHttp.emit('connection', handle);
        };
    });
}
```

**Client:**

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');

function connect(index) {
    connection = io.connect("http://my-ip-address", {
                                reconnection: true,
                                reconnectionDelay: 1000,
                                timeout: 3000,
                                multiplex: false });

    connection.on('connect', function (socket) {
        console.log(index + ': Connected');
    });

    connection.on('connect_error', function (e) {
        console.log(index + ': Connection Error: ' + e);
    });

    connection.on('message', function () {
        console.log(index + ': Server message');
    });

    connection.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(index + ': disconnect');
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(index) { 
        return function() { connect(index); }
    }(i), i * 5000);
};
```

The problem is that some of the clients in the above example managed to connect to the server and exchange messages, but the others failing on timeout, weirder then that I can see in the server's console that it received the connections for the timed-out clients but for some reason they don't succeed to communicate.

If I replace the server code to be on the same process this code runs perfectly.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found out this is a bug in Node.js, the problem is that there is auto-read machanism in Node.js sockets that starts to read out of every new socket automatically.

When we pass the socket to the child process it can either been read already or not, under heavy load there is more change that the socket will be read by the master (which of course is cuasing the problem), therefore we should explicitly ask to stop reading from this socket.

The following line is a nice workaround (should be added just before worker.send call):

```
connection._handle.readStop();
```

Source: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7905